# How to stop getting error report in Tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I created a JSP page to test how to connect to Oracle, I am using this code.

```
  String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING,
            "UMS", "d0801213177");
```

When something happens such as oracle is initializing or TNS is refusing to take more connection or the password of the database is changed then, I get an error report when I load my page. Which displays total connection string. If this happens when an user is using this page then my security is lost.

So, my question is **Is there any way to stop Tomcat form reporting errors?"**. If there are any better way then please tell.

**Follow up:** If I am using a prepared statements, errors like table/view doesn't exists these types of errors are general so do I need to put each block in separate try catch blocks?

## EDIT

As a beginer, I was struggling to hide the stackTrace because it was showing up my connection string, username, password too.

Now I know I should have never written this code in JSP in the first place. Using Servlet to do this task would have been a better

Answer (score 2):

JSP gives you an option to specify Error Page for each JSP. Whenever the page throws an exception, the JSP container automatically invokes the error page.

```
<%@ page language="java"  errorPage="" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Error Handling by try catch block in JSP</title>
</head>

<body>
<%
try{
     String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING,
        "UMS", "d0801213177");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
  out.print("Error caught by Catch block is : "+e.getMessage());
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Preferably you do the business logic inside a servlet and redirect it using requestDispatcher to a jsp.

Comment: So I need to put the whole code inside another try..catch block?

Answer (score 1):

I think the `errorPage` of the `page` directive. For instance, put this at the top of your .jsp page:

```
<%@ page errorPage="ExceptionHandler.jsp" %>
```

When you get an exception, it will be "caught" by the `ExceptionHandler.jsp` page, which will be able to handle it.

That `ExceptionHandler.jsp` page would be something like this:

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.*" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exceptional Even Occurred!</title>
    <style>
    body, p { font-family:Tahoma; font-size:10pt; padding-left:30; }
    pre { font-size:8pt; }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
    <%-- Exception Handler --%>
    <font color="red">
        <%= exception.toString() %><br>
    </font>
    <%
        out.println("<!--");
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        exception.printStackTrace(pw);
        out.print(sw);
        sw.close();
        pw.close();
        out.println("-->");
    %>
    </body>
</html>
```

... to enable that.

For more info, check details and a full example in this article: [Exception Handling in JSP Pages](http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2001072401&page=1).